# Get Today date & next 2 days - display in select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I want to display date in below options. Have to get today date and display next 2 days date in select component.

Plugin used - Selectize

**HTML:**

```
<select>
 <option value="31 Jul 2017">31 Jul 2017</option>
 <option value="1 Aug 2017">1 Aug 2017</option>
 <option value="2 Aug 2017">2 Aug 2017</option>
</select>
```

Sorry.. is there any possible solution available? Otherwise have to go with other approaches.

Thanks

Comment: *"today date"*... in which timezone? The user's or yours?

Comment: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: @Phil - User's time zone. Yes, we are using momentJS to get date and time. But, not sure how to display this in select option. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var dateRange = document.getElementById('date-range'),
    monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

for(var day = 0; day < 3; day++) {
  var date = new Date();
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + day);
  dateRange.options[dateRange.options.length] = new Option([date.getDate(), monthNames[date.getMonth()], date.getFullYear()].join(' '), date.toISOString());
}
```

```html
<select id="date-range">
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

For this you also can use [moment-transform](https://a----.github.io/moment-transform/).  it's really easy to achieve any date and time with one line of code, for what you want it should be like this :

```
moment().transform("YYYY-MM-+1 00:00:00.000") //This display the next day ( Tomorrow )

moment().transform("YYYY-MM-+2 00:00:00.000") //This display the day after tommorow
```

the key is `+1` & `+2` and so on. also you can show yesterday date if you use `-1` like :

```
moment().transform("YYYY-MM--1 00:00:00.000") //This display the Yesterday date
```

Comment: Superb solution. these values i add dynamically in select options and selectize plugin? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can use the date generated by moment-transform as your options value of your select or any other HTML elements.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/pp6ko79g/

```js
var today = new Date();
var month = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]

for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
 var tDate = new Date();
  tDate.setDate(today.getDate()+i);
 var optionDate = tDate.getDate() + " " + month[tDate.getMonth()] + " " + tDate.getFullYear();
 $('select').append('<option>' + optionDate + '</option');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var today = new Date();
var tomorrow = new Date();
var afterTomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate()+1);
afterTomorrow.setDate(today.getDate()+2);
console.log(tomorrow, afterTomorrow);
```

you can package and format the result, it will be what you expect.

Comment: Yes, thanks. But, i want to put these values in select option dynamically like i stated. this is wat confusing me. Sorry to trouble you.