# Select date 2 days from today only

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, calendar

I want to display date using a date picker. Need to get the today's date and display next 2 days date in select component.

Is this possible using JavaScript and jQuery?

I found a similar post but I want it to be on a date picker:
[Get Today date & next 2 days - display in select option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45406389/get-today-date-next-2-days-display-in-select-option/65086980#65086980)

```
<input type="date" id="" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```js
const date = new Date(2020,10,28,15,0,0,0); // today, remove the numbers inside when happy
document.getElementById("today").innerHTML = `Let's say today is ${date.toLocaleString()}`
date.setDate(date.getDate()+2);
let day = date.getDate();
const lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth()+1,0,15,0,0,0).getDate();
const sel = document.getElementById("day");

sel.options[sel.options.length] = new Option(day,day)
day = day+1>lastDay ? 1: day+1
sel.options[sel.options.length] = new Option(day,day)
```

```html
<span id="today"></span><br/>
<select class="select day" id="day">
  <option value="" selected="selected">DD</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I have an update on my question :)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can create using javascript and jquery.
check fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/s7nrfeqL/

html code

```
Select Date: <input type="date" id="datepicker"/><br>
    <select id="selectDay" class="select day">
</select>
```

javascript + jquery code

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    $( "#datepicker" ).on("change",function(){
        var dateRange = document.getElementById('selectDay'),
        monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", 
        "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
        $(dateRange).empty();

        for(var day = 1; day < 3; day++) {
          var date = new Date($( "#datepicker" ).val());
          date.setDate(date.getDate() + day);
          dateRange.options[dateRange.options.length] = new 
          Option([date.getDate(), monthNames[date.getMonth()], 
          date.getFullYear()].join(' '), date.toISOString());
        }

     });
})
```

create only the day which user need to select. Dont create 31 days and disable not needed days still user can select the disabled days due to client side code.

Comment: Thanks very much, I have an update on my question :)

Comment: if you use jquery datepicker you can limit the range to next two days alone

Comment: I got the date picker here: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

but there is no function that I can edit similar to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45406389/get-today-date-next-2-days-display-in-select-option/65086980#65086980

I want that similar function to be put on an input date picker:
<input type="date" id="" value="">

Comment: are you looking for something like this https://jsfiddle.net/v6krtmq9/

Comment: Almost :) format should be <input type="date" id="datepicker"/> and the date should start next 2 days which is December 3.

Comment: have you got your solution. try this https://jsfiddle.net/s7nrfeqL/